# mysql-server has stopped my ubuntu 17.10 apt functionality

Tags: apt, mysql

I cant do any `apt install/update/purge` at all. no matter what i do, i get a

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) ...
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through     socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

it doesn't matter what i want to do. remove, upgrade, install an app, remove mysql-server itself, in all situations i get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Not using SQL myself yet but it's been on my 30 year to-do list. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), I've summarized the steps:

To find all socket files on your system run:

```
sudo find / -type s
```

My Mysql server system had the socket open at /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Once you find where the socket is being opened, add or edit the line to your `/etc/my.cnf` file with the path to the socket file:

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**You still need to read the full answer** to get an appreciation of the whole environment and how changes effect **MySQL**.